# Where can I find the demonstration of $\sum_{j=0}^J \Delta x f(x_j) \to \int_0^1 f(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Let $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$. 
Define a partition $x_j = j \Delta x$ with $j=1,\ldots, J$ and $J\Delta x = 1$. Then, $\Delta x = \frac{1}{J}$.

I can't find the demonstration of 
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{j=0}^J \Delta x \left(f(x_j)\right)^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to \left( \int_0^1 \left(f(x)\right)^2 dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \quad 
\left(\Delta x \to 0\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: In most definitions of $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ in the Riemann sense, this is vacuous (i.e. it is built into the assumption that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ exists).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need a refer the result

Comment: Any undergraduate real analysis text, e.g. Rudin PMA, Strichartz The Way of Analysis, etc. will have it, although it will probably be stated in more generality.

Comment: Thank you again. I made a mistake. I edit  the question, but a think for the demonstration is same

Comment: It's the same situation, the only additional element is continuity of $x \mapsto x^{1/2}$.